# Summation Notation Representation

Tags: summation, induction

I have a question to ask.

May I know if the below equation is correct?

[image: Equation]

Explain the rationale behind it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try writing it out (say with $n=5$) and see what you get.

Comment: just a pointer for the OP ( prior to the edit) you can add an ! before the link to make the image appear here.

Comment: He's added and subtracted $1\cdot r^{1-1}$, so yes, the identity holds.

Comment: The "rationale" is simple: in the LHS we skip the term $i=1$ that amounts to: $1r^0=r^0$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be correct as 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}ir^{i-1} - r^{0} = \underbrace{\sum_{i = 2}^{n} ir^{i - 1} + (1\times r^{1-1})}_{= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}ir^{i-1}} - r^{0} = \sum_{i = 2}^{n} ir^{i - 1} + 1-1 = \sum_{i = 2}^{n} ir^{i - 1}
\end{align}